# ES6: create class with .next() property (iterationg property field value)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iterator, es6-class

Let's say I have a class called Frame:

```js
class Frame {
  constructor({height, width, offset_x, offset_y}) {
    this.params = { height: height, width: width };
    this.offset = { x: offset_x, y: offset_y };
  }
  // ..getters here
}
```

And I want to have a method, called `.next()` which will allow me to step over offset each time it's called. For example:

```js
const TestFrame = new Frame({ height: 10, width: 20, offset_x: 100, offset_y: 100})
const NextFrame = TestFrame.next()
console.log(NextFrame) 
/**
 * Should give me ( ...{offset_y: 110, offset_x: 120})
 * so the new offset_y = offset_y (100) + height (10)
 * and the offset_x = offset_x (100) + width (20)
 *
 */
```

I have heard about `yield` and `generators` but somehow I can't achieve it via **getters**. So I will appreciate any advice or example that you'll give me.

## What have I tried:

```js
class Frame {
  constructor({height, width, offset_x, offset_y}) {
    this.params = { height: height, width: width };
    this.offset = { x: offset_x, y: offset_y };
  }
  get next() {
    return new Frame({
      height: this.params.height,
      width: this.params.width,
      offset_x: this.offset.x,
      offset_y: this.offset.y + this.params.height
    })
  }
}

const Test = new Frame({ height: 20, width: 10, offset_x: 100, offset_y: 100 });
console.log(Test)
console.log(Test.next); //Frame { params: { height: 20, width: 10 }, offset: { x: 100, y: 120 } }
console.log(Test.next); //FIXME Frame { params: { height: 20, width: 10 }, offset: { x: 100, y: 120} } but should be ...y: 140
```

Comment: Do you want `.next()` to transform the current object or to produce a new one?

Comment: I'll be fine, even with producing a new one. I actually I am looking for a `.next()` implementation.

Comment: And the problem is? What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? Please share your attempt (preferable as snippet)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#simple_iterator

Comment: @VLAZ yes, I have seen this article, but does it will work with class? In that case. In their case example iterate over `[a,r,r,a,y]` with `.next`

Comment: Scroll to the top of that page and read the big blue block.

Comment: It will work. To fulfill the iterable protocol, you just need a method called `next()` that returns a specified object - with `value` and `done` properties. Doesn't matter where you implement it. I'm not sure how you intend to use this, however.

Comment: @RandyCasburn got it. Actually, this blue box with an explanation of *it is not possible to know reflectively whether a particular object implements the iterator protocol* doesn't represent in some other locales.

Comment: For class implementation see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#with_es2015_class on the same page.

Comment: @VLAZ now I know, so should I answer my own question, or you'd recommend me to delete it?

Comment: I'm still not sure how you intend to use the `next()` method. Do you need an *iterable*? That actually needs an `@@iterator` method. [Here is an example](https://jsbin.com/pasahopeqa/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: @VLAZ, No, that not what I wait. Guess, I explain my problem quite badly. This [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/feyaroluda/1/edit?js,console) example is relevant to what, I am trying to achieve.

Comment: What should happen in this case? Do you want `.next` to increase the offset every time? I'm not sure if it's relevant but you can [use `.next.next`](https://jsbin.com/yadurovufa/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: Yes, I'd prefer that `.next` will increase the `offset` field value each time. As for now, I'm trying to create a private field that will store something like: `next called`. Using chaining as `.next.next` is an option. But I prefer to use at least `.next(2)` if each time when `.next` method if called for this class can't been stored.

Comment: [So, this](https://jsbin.com/suyecoqora/1/edit?js,console)?

Comment: @VLAZ, yea, that is precisely what I am looking for now but in own my IDE. Except I am trying to make this `this.offset.counts` hidden (as a private field). *My lack of knowledge for ES classes make me shy each time you comment this question. But I am grateful for your help*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228959/discussion-between-alexzedim-and-vlaz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new frame every time `next` is read and keep track of the number of frames created. This will allow you to apply an ever progressing offset every is read:

```js
class Frame {
  constructor({height, width, offset_x, offset_y}) {
    this.params = { height: height, width: width };
    this.offset = { x: offset_x, y: offset_y };
    this.offsetCount = 0;
  }
  get center() {
    return { center: { x: (this.params.width - (this.params.width / 2)), y: (this.params.height - (this.params.height / 2)) } };
  }
  get next() {
    this.offsetCount++;
    return new Frame({
      height: this.params.height,
      width: this.params.width,
      offset_x: this.offset.x,
      offset_y: this.offset.y + (this.params.height * this.offsetCount)
    })
  }
}

const CharacterSelect = new Frame({ height: 20, width: 10, offset_x: 100, offset_y: 100 });
console.log(CharacterSelect)
console.log(CharacterSelect.next) //Frame { params: { height: 20, width: 10 }, offset: { x: 100, y: 120 } }
console.log(CharacterSelect.next) //Frame { params: { height: 20, width: 10 }, offset: { x: 100, y: 140 } }
```

I'd suggest an alternative - use a generator function that will generate infinite frames with offsets. This frees your `Frame` class from having to keep track of it all.

```js
class Frame {
  constructor({height, width, offset_x, offset_y}) {
    this.params = { height: height, width: width };
    this.offset = { x: offset_x, y: offset_y };
  }
  get center() {
    return { center: { x: (this.params.width - (this.params.width / 2)), y: (this.params.height - (this.params.height / 2)) } };
  }
}
const CharacterSelect = new Frame({ height: 20, width: 10, offset_x: 100, offset_y: 100 });
const frameGenerator = moreFrames(CharacterSelect);
console.log(CharacterSelect)
console.log(frameGenerator.next().value) //Frame { params: { height: 20, width: 10 }, offset: { x: 100, y: 120 } }
console.log(frameGenerator.next().value) //Frame { params: { height: 20, width: 10 }, offset: { x: 100, y: 140 } }

function* moreFrames(frame) {
  while(true) {
    const nextFrame = new Frame({
      height: frame.params.height,
      width: frame.params.width,
      offset_x: frame.offset.x,
      offset_y: frame.offset.y + frame.params.height
    });
    yield nextFrame;
    frame = nextFrame;
  }
}
```

Using a small helper you can only take a limited number of items from any iterable:

```
function* limit(number, iterable) {
  const it = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
  
  for(let i = 0, next = it.next();
      i < number && !next.done;
      i++, next = it.next()
  ) {
    yield next.value;
  }  
}
```

Which means you can only take as many frames as you want at a time:

```js
class Frame {
  constructor({height, width, offset_x, offset_y}) {
    this.params = { height: height, width: width };
    this.offset = { x: offset_x, y: offset_y };
  }
  get center() {
    return { center: { x: (this.params.width - (this.params.width / 2)), y: (this.params.height - (this.params.height / 2)) } };
  }
}

const CharacterSelect = new Frame({ height: 20, width: 10, offset_x: 100, offset_y: 100 });
const frameGenerator = moreFrames(CharacterSelect);

const first3 = [...limit(3, frameGenerator)];
const next5  = [...limit(5, frameGenerator)];

console.log(first3);
console.log(next5);

function* moreFrames(frame) {
  while(true) {
    const nextFrame = new Frame({
      height: frame.params.height,
      width: frame.params.width,
      offset_x: frame.offset.x,
      offset_y: frame.offset.y + frame.params.height
    });
    yield nextFrame;
    frame = nextFrame;
  }
}

function* limit(number, iterable) {
  const it = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
  
  for(let i = 0, next = it.next();
      i < number && !next.done;
      i++, next = it.next()
  ) {
    yield next.value;
  }  
}
```